# javascript shortest regex formatting account number

Tags: javascript, regex

The problem:
In my database I keep some account numbers in form:

PL83102044760000870200961284

Now I have to format it like this:

PL 83 1020 4476 0000 8702 0096 1284

I wrote simple js regex that do the job:

```
account.replace(/(\w{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{4})/g, '$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8');
```

But I fell this is somehow naive solution and this code can be refactored to avoid repetitions. Anyone can do this shorter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
"PL83102044760000870200961284".match(/.{4}/g).join(" ")
```

maybe?

Didn't notice the first requirement of "PL 83"

```
account.match(/.{4}/g).map(function(n){ return /([A-Z]{2})(\d{2})/.test(n) ? RegExp.$1 + " " + RegExp.$2 : n; }).join(" ");
```

To be honest, i would be tempted just to manually fix tat first bit rather than map, or i'm sure there's clever way to use match to do both...

This works too

```
account.match(/[A-Z]{2}|(?:(?:\d{2}|\d{4})(?=(\d{4})*$))/g).join(" ")
```

Answer (score 2):

Oh boy, once again regex when it is not needed at all.

```
function getFormattedAccountNo( accountNo ){

    var formattedAccountNo = '';
    for ( var i = 0; i < accountNo.length; i++ ){
         if ( formattedAccountNo.length == 2 || formattedAccountNo.length % 4 == 0 ){ 
             formattedAccountNo += ' ';
         }
         formattedAccountNo += accountNo.charAt(i);
    }
    return formattedAccountNo;
}
```

Comment: Oh boy, why imperative loop is better than elegant declarative regex?

Comment: Because simple string manipulations using inbuilt functions are ALWAYS better (more efficient, more readable, etc.) than regex. Also, this was just an example. Using substring will works just as well (see below for a solution)

Comment: Regular expressions are great, essential even... but slow. 1 regex won't make the difference, true. But if nobody tells the OP that regex shouldn't be the first place to look for a solution, he'll just start using regex all over the place. That WILL make a difference in performance. People should learn to look at the native methods JS provides to tackle these kind of problems befor turning to regex. 
My answer: no loop, no regex, just native JS methods and the result fits the OP's needs, too.

Comment: p.s. down the line substring will most likely be implemented through a loop and `charAt` :D

Answer (score 0):

This solution may be a little tricky :

```
"PL83102044760000870200961284".replace(/^(\w{2})(\d{2})(\d{24})$/, function(_, a, b, c) {
    return [a, b, c.replace(/(\d{4})/g, '$1 ')].join(" ");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best looking of solutions, but I agree with scibuff: Regular expressions are not the way to go in this case... here's a simple 1 line solution:

```
var str = 'PL83102044760000870200961284';
var formatted = str.substr(0,2)+' '+str.substr(2,2)+' '+str.substr(4,4)+' '+str.substr(8,4)+' '+str.substr(12,4)+' '+str.substr(16,4)+' '+str.substr(20,4)+' '+str.substr(24);
```

Console output: `"PL 83 1020 4476 0000 8702 0096 1284"`.